# Notify me if weather is gonna rain

Tags: android

Hi everyone i just want to ask, how will i be able to notify my phone
if its gonna rain like when you send a request for the current weather 
the request should run on background and if its gonna rain then it will notify.

Can anyone give some hints or any tutorial for me 
to able to send a request through a service and notify me 
if its gonna rain please share some ideas

cause i really need it and thank you.

i have done a class for requesting the current location and i use openweathermap API for me to get the current weather.

```
package com.example.autoapp;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class WeatherJSONParser {

    public WeatherJSONParser()

    {

    }

    public JSONObject getWeatherFromUrl(String url)
    {
        String holder= null;
        JSONObject jobj=null;
        try
        {
            HttpClient client= new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet get= new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse response= client.execute(get);
            StatusLine sLine= response.getStatusLine();
            int status= sLine.getStatusCode();


            if(status==200)

            {
                HttpEntity content= response.getEntity();
                InputStream iStream= content.getContent();
                StringBuilder cBuilder= new StringBuilder();
                BufferedReader bReader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));
                String cLine=null;
                while((cLine=bReader.readLine())!= null)
                {
                    cBuilder.append(cLine);
                }
                iStream.close();
                holder= cBuilder.toString();
                jobj= new JSONObject(holder);


                return jobj;
            }

        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


}
```

Comment: http://worldweatheronline.com/ go through this link they provide free weather api . I have integrated one. They provide you with the key and you get XML response. There is a element weatherDesc which will give you the info if it will rain or not. You can use that data

Comment: thanks for that API but i want to know on how will you be able to send a request through a service and notify you if its gonna rain do you have any ideas for that or any tutorial for that?

Comment: I don't have any tutorial But i can share some code with you . You can run that as a service at a regular interval of 15 mins or whatever you want to set.

Comment: so did it work? What was the condition to check if it's going rain?

Answer (score 1):

```
    private final String URL = "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?key=***your api key*****&q=00.00,00.00&cc=no&date=2010-04-23&format=xml";
        private static final String KEY_SONG = "weather"; // parent node

        // public variable
        public static final String KEY_TEMPERATURE_MAXIMUM = "tempMaxC";
        public static final String KEY_TEMPERATURE_MINIMUM = "tempMinC";
        public static final String KEY_WEATHER_DESCRIPTION = "weatherDesc";
        public static final String KEY_PRECIPITATION = "precipMM";
        public static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "weatherIconUrl";
    private  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> aList =null;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
new LongOperation().execute("");
}


 private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

         @Override
         protected String doInBackground(String... params) {




             aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

             XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();

             String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL


             Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml);

             NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);

             // looping through all song nodes <song>

             try {
                for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                    // creating new HashMap
                    map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(KEY_TEMPERATURE_MAXIMUM, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TEMPERATURE_MAXIMUM));

                    map.put(KEY_TEMPERATURE_MINIMUM, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TEMPERATURE_MINIMUM));

                    map.put(KEY_WEATHER_DESCRIPTION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_WEATHER_DESCRIPTION).trim());

                    map.put(KEY_PRECIPITATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_PRECIPITATION));

                    map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    aList.add(map);

                }
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

             adapter = new LazyAdapterForWeather(WeatherReportActivity.this, aList, 0);


            return "Executed";

         }      

         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
           if(mProgressDialog.isShowing()){
             mProgressDialog.dismiss();
         }
             list.setAdapter(adapter);

         }

         @Override
         protected void onPreExecute() {
         ShowLoading();
         }

         @Override
         protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

         }

     }
```

See in this way you can get the weather report . For running the same thing in service at regular interval 
you need to merge two code